# Property does not exist error even when added to the constructor Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

While creating a web app, I stumbled upon an unusual error in my IDE (VSCode) while working on one of the services:

`Error, property adapter does not exist in DetailDataService`

In most cases, this error is fairly straight forward, whatever I'm trying to add isn't declared, so I should declare the missing variable or whatever. However, in this case, the variable in consideration was already declared in the constructor.

```
constructor(
    adapter: SuiteAdapterService,
    toastr: ToastrService,
    translate: TranslatePipe
  ) {}
```

But whenever I gave reference to these in my functions (for example):

```
extractData(
    module: string,
    where_relate_field: string,
    where_field_value: string
  ): any {
    let params = this.initializeParams(
      module,
      where_relate_field,
      where_field_value
    );

    this.adapter.post("listRecords", params).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.records = response.records;
      },
      (error) => {
        let errmsg = this.translate.transform(
          "pages[login_page][responses][error][" + error.text + "]"
        );
        this.toastr.error(errmsg);
      }
    );
  }
```

The IDE shows me an error for all three (adapter, toastr, translate) that they do not exist. I found this strange because I have been doing the same for the rest of the services and they seem to be working perfectly fine. I thought there was an IDE issue so I changed to Atom but the error persisted. I ran `ng s` to see if it was just an IDE problem, but turns out the error is somehow legit as it throws me the following:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/dynamic-loading/data/detail/detail-data.service.ts(70,10): error TS2339: Property 'adapter' does not exist on type 'DetailDataService'.
src/app/services/dynamic-loading/data/detail/detail-data.service.ts(75,27): error TS2339: Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'DetailDataService'.
src/app/services/dynamic-loading/data/detail/detail-data.service.ts(78,14): error TS2339: Property 'toastr' does not exist on type 'DetailDataService'.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid. I forgot to declare the scope of the declarations in the constructor. It should have been:

```
constructor(
    private adapter: SuiteAdapterService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private translate: TranslatePipe
  ) {}
```

I find this confusing for a language that is not strictly typed to have constructor declarations that should have their scope defined. Perhaps that is a discussion for another day.

Comment: In a traditional constructor you don't have to declare the scope because the scope is that they are available within the constructor only (you would manually assign instance properties from the constructor arguments).  This automatic assignment is a special typescript feature: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties